# Work around for ClassPathResource in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using SpringBootApplication

I have used `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource` for getting file from the project classpath like shown below

```
File file = new ClassPathResource("File1").getFile();
```

My files are in the resources folder

This is working fine in the Spring STS.
I get  **IO Exception** when I export my project as WAR and deploy it in the TOMCAT container (Project folder structure changes when it is exported to WAR).

What is the work around for this issue?

Comment: `getClass().getResource`

Comment: Tried it @jack Flamp

Comment: and you have read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream