# What broke my getResourceAsStream?

Tags: java, android-studio, classloader

I'm taking over a project and have to assume that the tests worked at some point the way I find them (boiled down to what should not be null):

```
@Test
public void testCoding() {
   assertNotNull(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myfile.json"));
   //assertNotNull(MyTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/myfile.json"));
   //assertNotNull(MyTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myfile.json"));
   //...
}
```

with `myfile.json` in `src/test/resources/` and the test in `src/test/java/some/package/`.

I tried putting `myfile.json` into the same folder as the test, in the src/java folder, I tried with and without leading `/` and with `/resources` and all the tips I found on SO.

The gradle file is:

```
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    }
```

What am I missing?

---

Update:

I realized that the source code is in the open source part of our project and that it does fail in AS, only.

[Here is the line that fails](https://github.com/mycelium-com/wallet/blob/master/lt-api/src/test/java/com/mycelium/lt/location/GoogleMapsGeocoderTest.java#L45) if I right-click the `lt-api/src/test/java/` folder and select "Run All Tests". The Gradle console prints out this line:

```
    Executing tasks: [:lt-api:compileJava, :lt-api:testClasses, :mbwlib:compileJava, :mbwlib:testClasses, :bitlib:compileJava, :bitlib:testClasses]
```

Running
        ./gradlew clean :lt-api:compileJava :lt-api:testClasses :mbwlib:compileJava :mbwlib:testClasses :bitlib:compileJava :bitlib:testClasses

does not trigger the error but neither does it run tests. (How can I know what exactly AS is doing there? I thought AS was doing gradle all the way now?)

Running

```
    ./gradlew clean :lt-api:test
```

I get the tests to run (adding a typo results in failing tests) but it doesn't trigger the issue I originally had and that I'd like to understand.

Where should the file be?

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate test-classes
$ locate ungargasse.json
/path/to/project/lt-api/build/resources/test/ungargasse.json
/path/to/project/lt-api/src/test/resources/ungargasse.json
```

Comment: The acid test is where is it when you execute it? Does it get copied into the head of the class hierarchy? It seems to me the code should say `"/resources/myfile.json"`.

Comment: refer it it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream

Comment: It depends on how the project is build: is the directory src/test/resources/ in the classpath? or is its content copied in the classpath?

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry for slow response with kind of a change of issue towards AndroidStudio vs. Gradlew.

Answer (score 2):

**Be Sure that myfile.json is in the test-classe after you complied the codes.**

(By default,the files in *src/test/resources/* will automatically move into test-classes after compling)
[image]

You can use getResourceAsStream without leading "/" in two cases:

1. Test.java is in `src/test/java/some/package`  and myfile.json is in `/test/resource`

   ```
   src/test/java/some/package/Test.java
   src/test/resource/myfile.json
   ```
2. Test.java and myfile.json are in the same package

   ```
   src/test/java/some/package/Test.java
   src/test/java/some/package/myfile.json
   ```

For example

```
@org.junit.Test
    public void testCoding() {
        InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("myfile.json");
        System.out.println(resourceAsStream);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe there is a typo. /test/resources/, not resource/. I updated my question. Essentially I get the issue in Android Studio but not on the console using gradlew.