# A class from external jar throws exception while loading Resource

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, classloader

Hi I am working on a Maven project having dependency on a external jar which has a class `ConfigLoader` having following `loader()` method.

```
public class ConfigLoader {
   public void initialize() {
      loader();
   }
   private static void loader() {
      URL configURL = ConfigLoader.getClass().getResource("runtimeConfiguration.xml");
      //some other method calls to which configURL is an argument.
   }
   //other methods of ConfigLoader class
}
```

and the directory structure is like this -

```
src
|...main
|.......java
|.......resources
|................dev
|................prod
```

both dev and prod have a file named *runtimeConfiguration.xml*
and the code which uses this class is

```
public class Application {
   private Application application;
   public static void main(String []args){
      application = new Application();
      application.invokeConfigLoader();
      //additional code
   }
   private void invokeConfigLoader() {
      configLoader.initialize(); 
   }
}
```

The error I get is

```
could not find: runtimeConfiguration.xml
and the exception is thrown at the getResource() line in the class from jar.
```

I have tried adding the dev folder to classpath but still the same error. I want to run this code from linux terminal, and the command I am giving from trunk directory (where all my exernal jars and resource folder sits after maven build) is -

```
java -cp /resources/dev/*:configuration-loader.jar
```

I am using intelliJ 2017.2 and also tried to add the resources/dev folder as module dependency, but I keep on getting the same error. The resources folder is added as a library via project structure settings. I tried to search a lot but have not found any question with this issue. Kindly help me out as I am new to this environment based development.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConfigLoader.getClass().getResource("runtimeConfiguration.xml");` will try to get `runtimeConfiguration.xml` from the same package a the ConfigLoader is defined and not from the root of classpath. Try appending `/` to `runtimeConfiguration.xml`.

This should work `ConfigLoader.getClass().getResource("/runtimeConfiguration.xml");` or `ConfigLoader.getClass().getResource("/dev/runtimeConfiguration.xml");` depending how you are adding resources to your classpath.

See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) for more.

Comment: thanks for replying. The code which invokes this getResource is coming from an external jar, so I can't  make any changes there.

Comment: Then, try to put the file under the path same as package name of `ConfigLoader`. For example if `ConfigLoader` is under `com.yourcompant.config` then put `runtimeConfiguration.xml` under `com/yopurcompany/config` directory.

Comment: one query I have, if the config sits in say `src/main/java/com/yourcomapany/config` and the `runtimeConfiguration.xml` sits in `src/main/java/resources` where the `resources` directory is marked as resources root. Then should it work?

Comment: It should then sit in `src/main/java/resources/com/yourcomapany/config`.

Comment: Hi both the solutions are not working. Thanks for being kind to reply though.

Comment: btw is there difference between `ConfigLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("runtimeConfiguration.xml");`
and `URL configURL = ConfigLoader.getClass().getResource("runtimeConfiguration.xml");` ?

Comment: No. They are same. From javadoc: "This method delegates to this object's class loader."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream This discussion led me into thinking they are different.

Comment: Yes, if you are talking about how they treat the path.