# Relative path doesn't work when exporting to runabble jar on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, path, relative-path, runnable

I'm doing a Java project in Eclipse. I am using some relative paths such as:

```
File htmlTemplateFile = new File("src/templateGeno2Pheno.html");
```

instead of absolute paths:

```
File htmlTemplateFile = new File("/Users/.../Documents/workspace/SeqAnalysis/src/templateGeno2Pheno.html");
```

Everything works very well when I run it with Eclipse, but once I export it to a runnable JAR and execute it, it doesn't work.

This is my folder structure:
[image]

Here is my code:
[image]

Comment: Please put the actual code in your question rather than an image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308388/27905

Answer (score 0):

After packaging into a JAR then everything, including your HTML templates, are zipped up into that JAR and therefore filesystem paths aren't going to work for you.  Java doesn't have a file addressing system like your browser/html.

One option is to load those html templates using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` API.

Change your code to:

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/templateGeno2Pheno.html");
String htmlString = IOUtils.toString(stream);
```

IOUtils is from the Apache Commons IO library.

HTH

Comment: Hi, ok I understand now, but I still have an error after changing the lines:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMfUv.png

Comment: An empty stream? Or null? An empty stream would indicate that the path /templateGeno2Pheno.html is correct but the file is empty. Null would indicate that the path is not quite right. I cant remember exactly how the addressing works.  You could try just `templateGeno2Pheno.html`

Comment: Updated answer to use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`.  Try using that.  ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream will interpret the `/templateGeno2Pheno.html` path as absolute from the root of your src folder (i.e. classpath) whereas `Class.getResourceAsStream` interprets it as relative from where the class lives.  See this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream