# My icon image doesnt show up in JFrame on mac

Tags: java

My image for logo doesnt show up on mac. there is no java logo in Jframe to begin with?
what am I missing?

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("this is the frame title");
        frame.setSize(420,420);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("logo.png");
        frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());
    }       
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't try to load images via file-system paths (even if it would work now, you would have troubles after you wrap your code in JAR). Instead try to load them as project *resource*. You may want to read [Different ways of loading a file as an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/676250), [Loading resources like images while running project distributed as JAR archive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9864267)

Answer (score 2):

the mac OS will not show your icon, there's nothing wrong with your code, what you can do is enable the look and feel for cross platform. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) at the docs you can see how achieve this and configure it. Basically before start your jframe do this:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
// you can even set a theme on it
MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(new OceanTheme()); // since Metal is the L&F for cross platforms.
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```