# Spring boot images in src main resourcer aren't visible from java code

Tags: java, spring-boot, image

in a spring boot application, i have an image: src/main/resources/images/logo.jpg

I need to use that image creating new File, but this doesn't work:

```
File img = new File("/images/logo.jpg");
```

How can i do this?

Thankss

Comment: Does the image need to be in resources? Or do you have multiple images that get add dynamically?

Comment: Because it isn't a file but a classpath resource. Files from inside the classpath (and thus inside a jar at runtime) you cannot access as a `File`. Use a `new ClassPathResource("/images/logo.jpg");` and use the `getInputStream()` to read it.

Answer (score 1):

The resources folder should be in your classpath. This means you can access it like this:

```
@Service
class SomeClass {
  @Value("classpath:images/logo.jpg")
  private Resource img;

  private void methodThatUsesImage() {
    // you can do something here with the InputStream of img
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream/676273#676273) ways to load resource files, one practice is as follow

```
 ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
 File file = new File(cl.getResource("images/logo.jpg").getFile());
```

And in spring based project you can use

```
...
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("images/logo.jpg");
...
```

For not facing `FileNotFoundException` at runtime please see the attached link as well.

Comment: Be careful with the getFile() method though. If there is no actual file in the classPath at runtime you might get a FileNotFoundException. Reading the InputStream is fine though.

Comment: @Herry correct ! i point out the the link for inputStream practice already.

Answer (score 0):

1. new File("/images/logo.jpg");

java will look up in the "working directory/images/logo.jpg". it does not exist, right?

2. Your file is in src/main/resources so the correct is

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/images/logo.jpg");
File file = new File(url.getFile());
```